# system-config-printers issue

Tags: printing

I had initially configured a printer and the printer device stopped working so I removed it and reconfigured the printer incorrectly. I then removed that printer and reconfigured it correctly only to find that it still was not working.

I completely removed all printers and rebooted my machine and tried to reconfigure again; only to see it still was not working.

I then reconfigured but renamed the name of the printer and it worked just fine.

So my questions are:

1. Where is each printer configuration file saved at?
2. Where is the printer spool directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question:

1. Printer configuration file is located in `/etc/cups/printers.conf`
2. Spool directory is `/var/spool/cups/`